# Sql Query to get Mappings names under a particular folder from Informatica Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can anyone please help me out

Sql Query to get Mappings names under a particular folder from Informatica Database

Comment: Hi Kamal can you elaborate your question please. What do you mean "under a particular folder"

Comment: This question is unclear, please elaborate it otherwise it will be deleted

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Comment: You mean to say you need the mapping name in a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get mapping_names using this query

```
SELECT
M.MAPPING_NAME MAPPING,
CASE WHEN M.IS_VALID = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END IS_VALID,
FROM OPB_MAPPING M, OPB_SUBJECT S
WHERE M.SUBJECT_ID = S.SUBJ_ID
AND is_visible = 1;
```

So what do you mean under a folder?

Comment: hi Jim...i have couple of projects in informatica. i want all mappings of particular project.above query will give mappings of all projects altogether i guess

Comment: In this case, you have to manually enter the mapping names in the query. That is the only way as there is no any identifier to represent the mapping name in the database

Comment: If you are creating your mapping in a separate folder you can achieve what you need by querying folder name

Comment: actualy i have queried through folder name ..but i got more mappings in DB as compared to what actuly displaying in  front End  [ Informatia UI ].But i am suspecting is there is some filter criteria to show the mappings in UI. i want only mappings which are displaying in  Informatica UI Screen but in Db it displaying more than actual. i am confuse between isValid,isVisible,version_number columns, like which fields are taken into consideration while displaying in Information UI.

Comment: I am using below query         SELECT SUBJ.SUBJ_NAME FOLDER_NAME, MP.MAPPING_ID, MP.mapping_name FROM (SELECT * FROM(SELECT M.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.MAPPING_ID ORDER BY VERSION_NUMBER DESC) LATEST_VERSION FROM OPB_MAPPING M WHERE NVL(M.REF_WIDGET_ID,0) = 0)WHERE LATEST_VERSION = 1) MP,OPB_SUBJECT SUBJ WHERE MP.SUBJECT_ID(+) = SUBJ.SUBJ_ID AND SUBJ.SUBJ_NAME in ("+folderTitle+")

Comment: Database consists of deleted mappings as well

Comment: In front End [Informatica UI] 24 mappings are there but this query returns me 29 records. I want 24 records only. i am not understanding on what criteria those 24 records only displaying in UI.

Comment: You can provide mapping name in the query right? Or you need some other thing.

Comment: Yes Correct database consist of deleted mappings as well. but how can we identify which mappings are deleted.any info got stored in table regarding those deleted mappings?

Comment: Do you know the source name and target name used in the mappings?

Comment: I have some requirement something like on giving the subject name all corresponding mappings of particular subject which are displaying in UI needs to be fetched..no extra/less mappings needs to be fetched.

Comment: Yes i know source name and target names

Comment: Will it be useful for you, if you could get your mapping names using source name

Comment: No..Because in multiple projects source name could be same in that case it will return me mappings of multiple projects altogether

Comment: You have folder name as well. So you can use both source name and folder name to get your mapping name right? Or do some other projects are associated the same folders

Comment: Why i am telling you is, data base holds all the mapping names to gather in the tables. It can be filtered on the basis of mapping names or source and target names or folder names or created user names. Which is efficient to you?

Comment: When you are free, you can go through the link https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/ . Will be very much useful to you

Comment: Thanks Jim definitely i will go through above link....anyways i fixed the query  It worked for me now...once a mapping got deleted logically its version_status columns value got changed to  9 and when deleted physically it's version_status columns updated with value 10.  0 is the value for active mappings..!! so from Version_status column we can identify the deleted mappings status.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this from repository manager by writing a query. Repository Manager -> Tools-> Queries..-> Query Editor -> {Query}. Thanks !!